# Are there X-Men with mundane powers?

Tags: marvel, x-men

We all know the "cool" X-people

- Cyclops -- Can shoot laser beams from his eyes!
- Storm -- Can control the weather
- Wolverine -- Can heal rapidly, plus has those cool claws
- Shadowkat -- Can phase through matter
- Nightcrawler -- Can teleport
- Mystique -- Can shapeshift
- Magneto -- Can manipulate metals

And so forth. (I realize I'm oversimplifying their powers.)

However, genetics don't work in the interests of awesomeness. Are there X-people with more, uh, mundane powers? Like, a person can grow hair really fast, or has really strong fingernails, or can hold his/her breath for extra long (like 20 minutes vs. the usual 3 minutes), or can make things moist. Powers that, while useful to a degree, are ultimately fairly mundane.

I prefer canonical sources: scans of panels, Word Of God interview excerpts, etc.

Comment: Does the ability to influence warm air to stink count?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by mundane? Do you mean powers that have no practical use? Powers that are uncool? Or powers that are merely extensions of human-base powers (i.e. super human strength, is just mundane strengh++).

Comment: @bitmask - who was that?

Comment: @DVK: Basically every human being has that ability (I guess, we're even with not getting each other's puns, now).

Comment: There are real-life humans who can hold their breath for almost 20 minutes.

Comment: My beard can pierce skin. Does that count as a power?

Comment: +1 for the Dr. Horrible reference

Comment: http://superuseless.blogspot.com.au/

Comment: I always thought that 'Kid Omega' from X-Men-The Last Stand was pretty useless. He can make himself spiky like a hedgehog. Not very useful, unless you want to stick a load of papers to him so you don't lose them.

Comment: Prof. X offered Carol Danvers (Ms. Marvel) a place with the X-Men when she *didn't have powers*. However, she wasn't a mutant, and didn't accept.

Comment: There's always Forge, whose mutant ability is being SUPERNATURALLY good at engineering.  Most of the Morlocks have pretty ridiculous powers, though they aren't really X-Men

Comment: Jazz has blue skin. That's literally his only power. Does that count?>

Answer (score 19):

- [**Longneck**](http://xmenipedia.wikia.com/wiki/Longneck)

  as the name implies, he can grow his neck length (up to 6 feet as per Wikia).

  [image: Longneck]
- [**Dryad**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad_%28comics%29) (not sure if this is mundane enough for you):

  > Dryad had the mutant ability to communicate with plants much like a telepath can with people, which allowed her to manipulate plant life. It was not a particularly strong connection in that she had to actively maintain a link (a plant cannot simply call out telepathically to her mind) for communication to occur.

The next ones come to you courtesy of Cracked's [The 8 Worst X-Men Ever](http://www.cracked.com/blog/the-8-worst-x-men-ever/)

- **[Skin](http://marvel.com/universe/Skin)**

  > Skin's gray body possessed between 4-6 feet of extra skin that he could control to assist him in varying ways, such as to grapple opponents or swing on like a vine. When relaxed, Skin’s extra skin sagged, but by concentrating he could contract the extra skin. Skin’s extra skin also granted him a degree of resistance to physical injury, being highly resistant to punctures and tearing.
- **[Cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities)**

  > Cypher is a mutant who possesses a superhuman intuitive facility for translating languages, spoken or written, human or alien in origin. His superhuman skill is extended to his great facility in deciphering codes and computer languages, and he is also able to read inflection and body language, allowing him to understand the vast subtext of a conversation
- **Kylun**

  Mimiquing any sound. The Tape-Cassete-Man :)

Comment: I was going to nominate Cypher.

Comment: Cypher actually sounds very useful.  Especially for things like deciphering perl.

Comment: @Kevin - you can't decipher perl. It's a binary </OCD>. And deciphering Perl is easy, at least one written by half-competent software developer. Being in charge of Perl code reviews for a large chunk of people nowadays, I can decipher Perl written by less than competent developers, but you need a very rare and powerful mutant power of Refraining-From-Homicide for that.

Comment: Perl jokes aside, I do actually think such extensive translation ability (as described; I haven't actually heard of him before) is much more useful than mundane.

Comment: Cypher would be the definition of mundane - it's (maybe) the only Mutant ability that could be replicated by a normal human with sufficient time and intellect.

Comment: Are you kidding? Cypher's ability is awesome! TARDIS-awesome!

Comment: Indeed.  Having Cypher's power would be as good as having an NP oracle in your head.  You could answer questions like "Does chess have a forced win for white in 40 moves?"  Might as well be God as compared to other intellects.

Comment: Absolutely.  I've always felt that Cypher was useless only because the writers *totally* failed to understand what they'd created with his power.  (Consider: His power works on *body language*.  As far as Cypher's power is concerned... Krav Maga is a language.  Cypher can understand and use any martial art, just by seeing it.  And unlike Echo, that's not limited to copying the exact moves he's seen.)

Answer (score 9):

**[Charles Xavier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X) sought out mutants whose power, in his opinion, meant those mutants were destined for greatness with the proper development. Those mutants he sought to enlist were those whose powers could transform the world. I would first suggest that Charles Xavier was not looking for mutants with mundane abilities.**

I suspect useless or less useful mutations do exist, many of them were associated with physical disfigurements and were known to hide underground with the [Morlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlocks_%28comics%29) population. Other such enclaves of lesser capable mutations have been known to exist and several attempts have been made to allow lesser mutants an opportunity to exist in the open such as [Asteroid M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_M) and [Genosha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genosha)).

**Mutants with questionable mutations include:**

[**Maggot**:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggott) whose digestive system was made up of twin maggot-like creatures which could act independently of his body and could consume most matter. He was also capable of psychometic abilities.

[image]

[**Chamber**:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_%28comics%29) his mutant ability allowed him to project energy from a hole where his lower jaw should have been. Unable to eat or drink, he was sustained from this psychic energy. Depowered during M-day, his body was repaired and he gained new powers later.

[image]

[**Stacy-X**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacy_X): a mutant whose powers included pheromone control and a snake like skin. Now called Ripcord she uses technology to augment her formidable fighting abilities.

[image]

[**Husk**:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husk_%28comics%29) a mutant whose powers required she shed her skin to activate her power and release an unknown ability. The power was often of a defensive nature, increasing her strength or durability to varying degrees.

[image]

[**Cypher**:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_%28comics%29#Ultimate_Cypher) Started his career as one of the physically weakest mutants known. Because of the passive nature of his power, Xavier hoped he could pass unnoticed among humans but was later recruited by Emma Frost's Massachusetts Academy. He later died, but got better. He was semi-telepathic and a clairvoyant omniliguist, capable of speaking any language he came into contact with, whether it be spoken, written, computerized or even kinesthetic (body language). As he developed with a variety of unusual experiences, he can now also read weaknesses or flaws in any structure, technique or ability. With the addition of the techno-organic viruses within him, he is now one of the most formidable mutants alive.

[image]

**[Marrow:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_%28comics%29)** A mutant whose abilities allowed her to remove bones from her body providing her with clubs, knives and acting as body armor. Depowered during M-day. Her disfigurement remained.

[image]

**[Domino:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_%28comics%29)** Her power is the manipulation of probability fields that affect a person's luck. If you were her opponent, her luck improved, your luck got worse. Strangely enough she chooses a life as a mercenary and is amazingly successful. Lucky, I guess.

[image]

There are many other X-men whose initial power pedigree left something to be desired. Jubilee (energy plasmoids resembling fireworks), Rogue (touch stole consciousness and later superpowers), Gambit (power converts matter to energy, likely a problem during puberty), Mystique (mutable appearance), Nightcrawler (physical appearance), Skin (mutable skin, ugh) but it is not just the mutation, but the training that makes the difference in how the power is used, perceived and developed. There are probably not enough of the kind of examples you are looking for, but if their powers were too mundane, they would probably never grace the pages of the X-men.

Comment: Tempted to -1 for including Domino and Stacy-X. Nothing remotely mundane there.

Comment: Tempted as well, but so many pretty pictures.

Comment: Loving a character and looking at their powers as less than spectacular are two different things. Uncontrolled probability manipulation is just not awesome and pheromone control that required you touch the target is also less than stellar. Coolness notwithstanding. Is there a particular reason no matter what I write, I get flack here?

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - don't know the answer to generic question, but in this case you're mistaking **mundane** powers with **uncool** powers. Plenty of X-men are uncool or outright ridiculous. I have explicitly rejected them from my answer, because, despite being uncool or ridiculous, they are **NOT mundane** powers wise. Affecting probability is arguably not awesome (I disagree but I can see where you can think that), but not exactly what one'd consider **mundane**, no?

Comment: Thadeus, your answer is great for a wiki or another question but there's too much information to parse to get to the good bits. Pair is down a little and It'll be much better.

Comment: *"He later died, but got better."* - lolwut

Comment: As a statistician, Domino is my new favorite mutant. Wonder if her powers extend to the atomic/quantum realm? Can she make gases spontaneously heat up, or use quantum teleportation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though I've limited my search to the remaining mutants after M-day, this is the only ones I've found:

> Kylun is a mutant who possesses some animalistic physical characteristics, such as fur, sharpened teeth, and a lion like nose and eyes. He also has the ability to use his vocal cords to replicate any sound he has heard.

First appeared in Excalibur #2

Comment: +1 for Kylun. -1 for Gregor. How is transforming into a TREE mundane?

Comment: As per my understanding of mundane. *All of these are either mundane in that they do nothing useful on a superhero team*. I dunno, that sounds mundane to me.

Comment: @DVK ON second thought, seeing your comment to Thadeus, I'll remove Gregor.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Squirrel Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_Girl), who has squirrel-like physical abilities and can control squirrels. She defeated Dr. Doom when Iron Man couldn't, so I don't know if she's mundane enough to fit your criteria.

Comment: When offscreen, Squirrel Girl is the most powerful hero in the Marvel universe.

Comment: Is she X-men affiliated? She seems from Avengers, not X-men. But yeah, very mundane! Here squirrelly squrrelly! Fetch!

Comment: @Izkata - She made short work out of Deadpool too.

Comment: Squirrel Girl is not a member of the X-Men, and she can't control squirrels.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an X-Man, [Sammy Paré](https://www.marvel.com/characters/squid-boy) was an student at the Xavier Institute for higher learning. His mutant ability was the ability to speak and breathe underwater.