# Are there any heroes/villians with only super weaknesses?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, super-hero

If you have ever seen *Unbreakable*,

> Samuel L Jackson's character has a kind of reverse super power:  he is incredibly susceptible to injury and illness. Everyday activities could kill him. There is no upside to having very brittle bones.

Is there anything like this in the X Men?

Another example of what I am looking for would be Christopher Snow in Dean Koontz's

Fear Nothing:

> This character could not go out in the sun, he burned easily, his skin could not ever repair the damage and eventually he was sure he would die from skin cancer young. There were no benefits to this (like in a vampire where there are trade offs). His illness was ONLY a hindrance.

Comment: Like half the morlocks have no benefit to their mutation.

Comment: I edited my question to emphasize the harmful part (super weakness).

Comment: Harmful to themselves or others around them?

Comment: voting to close until "harmful" can be clearly defined.

Comment: If we're trying to get clarification on what OP wants, why would you change the main question back to the original version?

Comment: @phantom42 - Agreed. Not clear.

Comment: @dvk - They aren't directly harmful to her, though. Arguably her ability to possess people's talents saves her life at least 2-3 times

Comment: @Richard rogue's absorption of carol danvers left her in a very volatile and dangerous mental state for a long time. temporary absorption has no lasting effects, but misuse of her powers can have lasting effects on herself.

Comment: Thank you Wad for the editing. I think this is much more clear. Something that makes you extremely susceptible to injury. As Richard stated..."directly harmful". I may add, with no upside.

Comment: Doesn't this seem similar to: [Are there X-Men with mundane powers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/are-there-x-men-with-mundane-powers)

Comment: @Thaddeus I don't think so. A trade for a mundane power would be welcomed by anybody with a mutation like I am describing. I am talking about something that is harmful.

Comment: @Seanoseanohay xmen only, or any character?

Comment: I did say xmen, but any marvel character would be interesting. If it were more broad the 2 examples I gave would already answer it.

Comment: Then I would say you won't find too much. Characters whose powers are ONLY liabilities don't live long in the comics unless they develop some other skills or abilities first. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @Seanoseanohay in one of the xmen movies, first i think, when the good guy enters the bad guys den, there's a young asian looking guy whose only power seems to be to grow spikes from his face... pretty lame i think. Also check for the crystal man, the bad guy from unbreakable. He has ultra-fragile bones.

Comment: @Seanoseanohay - One might argue that Daredevil's power (blindness) is actually a liability, but he'd probably disagree.

Comment: @WadCheber I thought about that, I think we would then have to add Dr. Xavier. I mean not being able to walk would suck too. Isn't daredevil's blindness separate from his ability though? If he got his site back could he still use his hearing power?

Comment: Elijah Price's infirmity appears to have given him a sense of purpose. It's arguable that he's the one who's unbreakable (in the sense of possessing an indomitable will), not Willis' character.

Comment: @Richard I like that interpretation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to put in a shout for [Wraith](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hector_Rendoza_(Earth-616)). His X-gene superpower is to become invisible, which sounds awesome except that he can only make his **skin** invisible. All his internal organs and bones are still plainly visible.

On top of that his strength is slightly weaker than human-normal so his only real ability is make small children scared.

[image]

Comment: Less than human strength and the possibility to get skin cancer on your internal organs...I would say we have a winner...

Comment: For the record, he can also transfer his ability to make his skin invisible to other mutants. Once he's done that, he's basically human-normal until he recharges,